Kyverno Precondition using JMESPath Filter Projection Skipped
I have the following ClusterPolicy and Deployment resources with a precondition that should trigger when a specific container c2 has a memory request greater than 1Gi:
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: enforce-memory
spec:
  rules:
  - name: require-memory-less-than-16Gi
    match:
      any:
      - resources:
          kinds:
          - Pod
    preconditions:
      any:
      - key: "{{ request.object.spec.containers[?name=='c2'].resources.requests.memory}}"
        operator: GreaterThan
        value: 1Gi
    validate
      ...
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        name: c1
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 100Mi
      - env:
        name: c2
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 16Gi

In this policy, I am using a Filter Projection to filter by the c2 container because it's the only one I care about. However, when the policy is evaluated in the Kyverno Playground, the ?name=='c2' filter projection is Skipped.

If I modify the policy to use an index-based filter (e.g. spec.containers[1].resources), the condition is met as expected.

So my question(s) are:

Are JMESPath Filter Projections supported in Kyverno?
If so, why is the ?name=='c2' filter projection skipped in my example?

Link to Kyverno Playground example.

The filter projection returns a list of items matching the filter. Since the list is expected to have 0 or 1 elements, we need to select index 0 by appending | [0] at the end of the statement.
{{ request.object.spec.containers[?name=='c2'].resources.requests.memory | [0] }}
Note, an out-of-bounds exception here does not throw an error in the context of Kyverno and causes the precondition to be skipped when the container's name does not match the literal c2 (as expected). The original statement was skipped for similar reasons because [16Gi] > 1Gi is not the correct comparison.
